# How can I fix Cassandra startup error "IllegalArgumentException: [...] is already bound in reverseMap"?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, java

We have a Cassandra cluster with three nodes installed on Ubuntu, but we are getting the below startup error while restarting the cluster. The same error occurs for all the three nodes.

Can anyone please help with the solution to restart the Cassandra cluster?

```
ERROR

ERROR [main] CassandraDaemon.java:731 - Exception encountered during startup

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: c997e340-2939-11e9-bf8c-edeff921e924 is already bound in reverseMap to (cli_150,mmmm_track)
```